# Docker NPM Cannot get private module / repo from Github

Tags: node.js, git, docker, github, npm

I try to build a docker image but I cannot pull the private module from Github. I am using https in my package.json but when doing docker build ssh is used, I don't know why...

```json
"dependencies": {
    "my-pkg": "git+https://GITHUB_TOKEN:x-oauth-basic@github.com/myuser/my-pkg.git#tag
},
```

docker build errors

```
#9 33.09 npm notice
#9 33.10 npm ERR! code 128
#9 33.10 npm ERR! command failed
#9 33.10 npm ERR! command git ls-remote ssh://git@github.com/myuser/my-pkg.git
#9 33.10 npm ERR! Host key verification failed.
#9 33.10 npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
#9 33.10 npm ERR!
#9 33.10 npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
#9 33.10 npm ERR! and the repository exists.
```

I've tried including the git insteadOf in my Dockerfile

```
RUN git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf git@github.com:
RUN git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

But still, I didn't get it to work...

Comment: Can this https://alysivji.github.io/docker-tips-private-git-repo.html help you?

Answer (score 0):

In your docker container you need to run ssh-keyscan and add it to ssh known hosts

```
RUN touch /root/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN ssh-keyscan -H github.com > /root/.ssh/known_hosts
```